# Can't create any 'Outcomes' in a custom task in Designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, tasks

When I create a custom task in Designer it doesn't give me any 'Task Outcomes' options or allow me to add new outcomes.  Designer won't allow me to publish the workflow until there are outcomes in the custom task. Any idea why this is?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has now been resolved by installing a fix, here's a link to the Microsoft update: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2752031#appliesto

The error occurred when Microsoft Designer couldn't start Visio, as described here:

"Issue that this update fixes: 
Assume that you install SharePoint Designer 2013 on a computer that has Microsoft Visio 2010 installed. When you open the workflow gallery or create a SharePoint Server 2013 workflow, you receive the following error message repeatedly: 
Microsoft SharePoint Designer can't start Microsoft Visio. An error occurred and this feature is no longer functioning properly. Would you like to repair this feature now? Yes / No"